# ag-grid select first row when grid opens

Tags: ag-grid

From the example in:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#example-custom-paging

Is the grid capable of:

When grid opens need to highlite the top data row and first editable cell as when a cell is clicked by the mouse

User will press enter to start editing that cell

As the user moves down or up with the keyboard, the row should also be highlighted as if clicked by the mouse each time

I will use it with pure javascript not other packages

Need to use edittype cell not by rows

Need full keyboard control without mouse and select cells within javascript

Comment: Please provide some examples you have done...